# importing data from postgreSQL to R: characters conversion

Tags: r, windows-1252

I have a table stored in a postgreSQL and a column(named `js`) has the following format:

[image]

I am using the following code to import the data:

```
library('RPostgreSQL')
drv <- dbDriver('PostgreSQL')
CON <- dbConnect(drv,host='bi*********zonaws.com',port=****,user='****',password='*****')
dbGetQuery(CON,'SELECT js FROM ln2 LIMIT 1')
```

and I have the following resulst for the first row:

```
{"id": "pub%2Fc%25C3%25B3nal-o-meara%2F27%2F4a5%2F933", "age": null, "name": "CÃ³nal O'Meara", "emails": [] }#continues but i stop it here. . . .
```

My question is this conversion in some letters. In the original table the name is `Cónal O'Meara` and in the imported in R is `"CÃ³nal O'Meara"`. How can I overcame that?

Comment: First, make sure the field's type is Unicode. Anything else is just a quick-fix that may or may not work eg with Danish data. If the field *is* Unicode, there may be a bug in the package you use that doesn't treat Unicode properly - there are a lot of such issues with various packages in R.

Comment: The quick-and-dirty fix is to change the environment codepage of R with `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","...")`, to the codepage used by the database field.